# Errors Routing to a page with Tabs in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing, ionic-tabs

I'm getting the error "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin-home/admin-fixtures'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin-home/admin-fixtures'"
When I'm trying to route to page containing tabs

My home page is also a tabs page (generated originally from ionic) and thats the example I'm trying to follow.

Here is my code which I think is relevant. On 1 of my pages Login.mhtl I click a button which links me to admin-home which should be a page containing 3 tabs

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('admin-home');
```

Here is the code for my admin-home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="dark" class="ion-icon-toolbar">
       <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-button (click)="goBack()"><ion-icon slot="icon-only" 
name="arrow-back"></ion-icon></ion-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Admin Home</ion-title>
        <ion-buttons slot="end">
       <ion-button (click)="logOut()">
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="log-out"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
     </ion-buttons>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab-bar slot="top">
    <ion-tab-button tab="admin-fixtures">
      <ion-label>Fixtures</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

      <ion-tab-button tab="admin-players">
      <ion-label>Players</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="admin-admins">
      <ion-label>Admins</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>

</ion-content>
```

And here is the admin-home.router.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminHomePage } from './admin-home.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'admin-home',
    component: AdminHomePage,
    children: [
      { path: 'admin-fixtures', loadChildren: '../admin-fixtures/admin-fixtures.module#AdminFixturesPageModule'},
      { path: 'admin-players', loadChildren: '../admin-players/admin-players.module#AdminPlayersPageModule'},
      { path: 'admin-admins', loadChildren: '../admin-admins/admin-admins.module#AdminAdminsPageModule'},
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/admin-home/admin-fixtures',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes) 
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminHomePageRoutingModule {}
```

Adding the admin-fixture.module.ts code

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AdminFixturesPage } from './admin-fixtures.page';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([{ path: '', component: AdminFixturesPage }])
  ],
  declarations: [AdminFixturesPage]
})
export class AdminFixturesPageModule {}
```

Comment: Do you have a child routing module loaded with the `admin-fixtures.module`?

Comment: @chrismclarke I've added the admin-fixture.module.ts

Comment: Any idea @chrismclarke?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell on inspection, would you be able to make a minimal stackblitz or similar?

Answer (score -1):

**You are getting this error because you are trying to route with the wrong page URL.**

*"Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin-home/admin-fixtures' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin-home/admin-fixtures'"

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/admin-home/admin-fixtures');
```

### OR

```
  this.router.navigate(['/admin-home/admin-fixtures']);
```

***Change your code like this (code shown above). On behalf of (code shown below)***

```
 this.router.navigateByUrl('admin-home');
```

*Maybe this will help you...*